# Previous Hour or X Minutes in TSQL Snapping to Window

Tags: t-sql, time

In TSQL, how can I can get the previous hour snapping to the hour.

So for example, if it was now 2:33, how would I get fields where `CreationDate` (a datetime field) is greater than or equal to 1:00 and less than 2:00.

I would also like to to do this with 10 minute intervals (snapping to the previous :00 - :10 if it were currently :14 for example, or another example, :50-:00 if it were :06).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would get you the start and end of the current hour:

```
select  dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, getdate()), 
            dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate())))
,       dateadd(hour, 1+datepart(hour, getdate()), 
            dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate())))
```

Explanation: `dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))` gets you the start of today.  Then you add the current hour to that.

Along the same lines for the previous 10 minute block:

```
select  dateadd(minute, datepart(minute, getdate()) / 10 * 10 - 10, 
            dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, getdate()), 
                dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))))
,       dateadd(minute, datepart(minute, getdate()) / 10 * 10, 
            dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, getdate()), 
                dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))))
```

Or another way of writing it:

```
declare @lowerBound datetime = dateadd(minute, datepart(minute, getdate()) / 10 * 10 - 10, 
            dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, getdate()), 
                dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))))

declare @upperBound datetime = dateadd(minute, datepart(minute, getdate()) / 10 * 10, 
            dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, getdate()), 
                dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))))

select @lowerBound, @upperBound
```

PS keep up the good work on Stack Overflow performance!

Comment: `CurrentDate LowerDate UpperDate
2011-05-10 20:07:10.243 2011-05-10 20:00:00.000 2011-05-10 20:10:00.000` Seems be the current 10 minute block

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: Right, answer edited to show the previous 10 minute block.

Comment: Ah, you beat me by two seconds :-P